# Calculated Column returns excessive amount of zeros

Tags: calculated-column, number

In a Purchase Order form I'm putting together, I have line amount and total amount as calculated columns. However, when displayed in the InfoPath form, they show with a ridiculous amount of zeros at the end. For example:
Total Price 45.0000000000000

I've tried formatting the field as both currency and number, and also specifying 2DP, but this makes no difference. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you outputting the calculated column as? Text or currency?

Comment: @PirateEric I've tried currency and number. I suppose I could just use text. But then can a text column be fed into another calculated column, if it uses addition? Cheers.

Comment: You should be able to, you'd just do a =Sum([Calc Column],[Other Column])